# CDF - Finding a probability

Tags: statistics

The cdf of $X$ is

$$
F(x) = \cases{0 & $x \leq 0$\\\frac{x}{2} & $0<x \leq 1$\\\frac{x^2-1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}& $1< x \leq 2$}
$$

Find $P(0.5 < X < 1.5)$

I tried solving this problem by solving for $F(1.5)$ and $F(0.5)$ and adding (not subtracting) them.

For $F(1.5)$ I got $43/144$ and for $F(0.5)$ I get $1/16$

When I add them I get $0.36111$.

Comment: Why don't you subtract them as was your original (correct) intention?

Comment: Sorry about that...  I was supposed to add them but I still didn't get the right answer.

Comment: Also $F(1.5)\ne 43/144$ and $f(0.5)\ne 1/16.$ Don't know how you're getting that. Particularly, $F(1/2) = (1/2)/2 = 1/4.$

Comment: You are supposed to subtract them. (Well technically you are supposed to subtract $F(0.5)$ from $F(1.5^-)$ but $F$ is continuous at $1.5$, so $F(1.5) = F(1.5^-)$)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know what I was thinking. For some reason I did an integration so I got some weird values. All I needed to do was to plug in the numbers directly to the given equations.